# Android - save activity state and list view items

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview

I currently have a `listview` that is self populated by the user. I would like it so that when the user leaves the activity and comes back, everything the user added is still in the `listview`. I have been reading about onSaveInstanceState, but I don't know if that is the right way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming if the user is populating some data, then that data has a store somewhere (SQLite, cloud, etc...). I recommend aggressively storing anything the user enters (i.e. as soon as they click "new" and enter the new list item, push to the database and refresh list). So when the applications onResume() is called, you can grab the data from its source and re-populate the list view. Saving temporarily into SharedPreferences sounds cumbersome (for a list of items).

Answer (score 1):

Its not exactly what you need; `onSaveInstaceState` saves the instance before the system kills your activity to reclaim resources (low memory), not if the user explicitly exits it.

If you wamt to save the activity state so whenever the user enters it will stay the same, you must save the data on file/shared preferences/using content providers.
If all you want to do is to save local data of a single listview's items, I'll recommend using Shared Preferences as it's very easy and intuitive. Read about them [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the Activity is not destroyed between leaving and returning then your data should be where the user left it (unless you do some reinitialization in on resume). However you can't count on that, as Android may free up resources when needed, and non-running Activitys may fall victim of such an act.

Therefore you should - as forementionned - save your data to persistent storage. If it's just for this Activity, and it's only a small amount of data, then SharedPreferences is a good and easy solution. Save in onPause(), load in onResume() and you'll only lose data when the phone dies with your Activity up front.

I wouldn't recommend using files for this, but if your data has to be accessed by different views, processed, sorted, filtered etc. than you may want to think about SQLite.